# JFace TableViewer Truncate and Expand ColumnLabelProvider Text as Column Expands

Tags: label, jface, provider, tableviewer

I have a JFace TableViewer with 5 columns.  One column may have a long String in it.  This test is set in the ColumnLabelProvider by calling the `getText(Object element)` method.

Currently the text is truncated at the end of the String to the column width and ends with "..." which adds characters to the text when the user adjusts the size of the column width.

I would like to have this behaviour, but with the "..." in the middle of the text  String so the user can see the first part of the text and the end of the text no matter what the size of the column currently is set.

For example my column currently truncates "`this is a long piece of text larger than the column width`" 
to 
"`this is a long piece of text larger...`"

and I would like to have it display

"`this is a long piece ... column width`" 
but also to have this text expand from the middle when the column width is expanded and contract again when the column width is contracted.

Any thoughts on how I might achieve this using Jface Tableviewer in an RCP E4 application?

It would be nice if I can override the existing method which is truncating the text at the end of the text String.

Comment: I think this is done by whatever native control the Table uses and varies depending on the OS (doesn't happen on macOS for example). This makes it hard to change. You could probably do it with OwnerDrawLabelProvider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I had to create a method inside the column label provider which takes the full text and column width - measures the current width of the column and takes the length of the text in the label provider and splits it according to the width of the column.  As the column expands substring1 and substring 2 grow.  Putting substring1 at head and substring2 at tail with the ellipsis in the middle.  It far from efficient code but works for our purposes.  I added a ControlListener to the Column and performed an @Override of controlResized(ControlEvent e) method which will refresh the Viewer in which the column resides upon resize of the column.